# How do I echo within preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, echo

Feeling stuck. Can't find an answer on stackoverflow. I need to echo $subcat and $cat inside preg_replace. It's not working. Is there a way to echo inside a preg_replace?

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', '<a href="https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=$1&subcatid="'. $subcat .'"&view=ads&catid="'. $cat .'"">#$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: put your full code with `$cat`, `$subcat` and `$text` value

Comment: @MrK Please complete your question by adding the input strings and your desired output string.  Even if you have received an answer that helps you, offering a complete question means that you may receive a higher quality answer AND it means that future researchers will better understand the question and the answers provided.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this? after putting those variable within curly brace `{var}`

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', '<a href="https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=$1&subcatid={$subcat}&view=ads&catid={$cat}">#$1</a>', $text);
```

**OR**

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', '<a href="https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=$1&subcatid='.$subcat.'&view=ads&catid='.$cat.'">#$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Shows them as {$subcat} and {$cat}. When I echo them outside the preg_replace they show just fine.

Comment: plz put your full code with all 3 variable. Then I'll edit my answer

Comment: Your second example is working. So I just put double quotes for nothing there. Thanks.

Comment: In the first example all treat as string , double quotes  can replace variable with its value.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the variables in double quotes when it's not needed. Removed it.

**Try:**

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', '<a href="https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=$1&subcatid='. $subcat .'&view=ads&catid='. $cat .'">#$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. I put double quotes that were not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from param value inside href, Use `"` double quotes to replace variable by its value , also escape `$1` to make it text

```
   $text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', "<a href='https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=\$1&subcatid=$subcat&view=ads&catid=$cat'>#\$1</a>", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern can be condensed a little with an `i` pattern modifier and be made more efficient by omitting the capture group and using `\K` to restart the fullstring match.  Also, your replacement string can be written without using dot-concatenation by using `\\0` or `\$0` to represent the fullstring match (which otherwise would be written (unescaped) as `$0` or `\0`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VguUV))

```
$subcat = 1;
$cat = 2;
$text = 'This is a non-qualifying#HashTag and this has white space before it #Test9 and some more text.';
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\S)#\K[\da-z]+/i', "<a href=\"https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=\\0&subcatid=$subcat&view=ads&catid=$cat\">#\\0</a>", $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
This is a non-qualifying#HashTag and this has white space before it #<a href="https://somesite.com/search?cityid=0&lang=en&search=Test9&subcatid=1&view=ads&catid=2">#Test9</a> and some more text.
```